# Handling lifetime and iterator validity when returning filtered ranges in C++20

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

I'm working with filter adaptors in C++20. However, I'm facing a problem when I try to return a filtered range from a function. The issue arises because the filter adaptor caches the iterator of the underlying range. When i return from the function, the underlying range gets copied but the iterator still points to the old range. This can lead to undefined behavior when attempting to use the filtered range. This only happens when i consume the filtered range before returning since thats when the caching occurs

I have a simplified example in compiler explorer to illustrate my problem

[Example](https://godbolt.org/z/nz7d1E197)

I would like some advice on how to avoid situations like this. Should we not call begin() on a view before returning it from a function as a rule of thumb?

Comment: First, always put the code *in the question*. Second, this is just a libstdc++ bug that was fixed at some point. gcc 11.2 and gcc 12.1 both are happy with the program (as they should be).